# how to setup ssh and "ssh_config" file correctly

Tags: ssh

I have noticed while learning how to setup **ssh** that lots of stackoverflow posts referred to the file `ssh config` being inside of the folder `~/.ssh` but when i look at the same folder in my macbook the files listed are:

## created from my last ssh setup

```
someprivatekey
someprivatekey.pub
known_hosts
```

now when i inspect the folder `cd /etc/ssh/` then i can see the file `ssh_config` there.

Is it a normal behavior or should ssh file `"ssh_config"` always be located in `"~/.ssh"` folder and I have presumably a wrong configuration?

(Sorry if the post sound very elementary, i am learning how to use `ssh`)

how to should i setup ssh and the "ssh_config" file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file in `/etc/ssh` affects all users on the machine, while the one in `~/.ssh` affects only you. You can find a complete list of the file locations at the end of the ssh [manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) (which should be available at your computer by running `man ssh`).